# Cannot index minified ExtJS files in Eclipse or Aptana

Tags: eclipse, extjs, indexing, aptana

it took me some time to find out that both Eclipse and Aptana get stuck when trying to index or read newly copied CSS files from ExtJS. (ext-all.css, ext-all-gray.css, ...)

The problem seems to be because these files are minified to one line.

I use Linux Ubuntu 32-bit and my CPU goes more than 100% forever and I have to kill Aptana/Eclipse.

I have already tried to fix it by deleting project settings, clean project... nothing helped. Only trimming the minified files (200.000 chars) to only say 200 char, then it works.

Any solutions?

Comment: I just [reported this](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4855) as an issue. I suspected the files to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194558-Cannot-index-minified-ExtJS-files-in-Eclipse-or-Aptana&p=776905&viewfull=1#post776905